# Leading "?" when parsing data with SAX

Tags: java, sax

I've run into a problem several times when parsing text in a utf8 and xml file. It's placing a leading "?" on the first piece of data I parse.

Here is the XML:

```
<dictionary>
  <word id="1" level="1" simp="爱" trad="愛">
    <pinyin>ai4</pinyin>
    <part>verb</part>
    <definition>to love</definition>
  </word>
```

Here is the SAX:

```
@Override
    public void startElement(String namespaceURI, String localName,
                String qName, Attributes atts) throws SAXException {
        if (localName.equals("word")) {
            word = new Word();
            word.setId(atts.getValue("id"));
```

When it pulls the first id it pulls "?1" instead of just "1", but it doesn't do it for any of the data after than point. The exception it throws is:

04-30 21:42:42.240: E/AndroidRuntime(1418): Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: unable to parse '?1' as integer

I don't see a "?" when I physically open the XML file, so where is it coming from? Why is it only effecting the first thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that you have an encoding problem. Does your input file have the declaration

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
```

If you don't have an encoding then anything can happen.

Have you created these files with encoding set on all of them? Because otherwise some tools may corrupt the encoding. especially cut-and-paste or certain text-editing tools.

Comment: It seems you've indirectly solved my problem. My generated XML files included standalone="no", I only noticed it when I compared it against what you posted. When I removed it away went the question mark.

Comment: Any ideas or wisdom on why including that would mess everything up?

Comment: without further indication of what your full files are , I cannot help. I am guessing that your file references a DTD, and that in this DTD are character entities (or some other entities) and that these are resolved during parsing. Assuming you have a DTD it could help to know what it is - yours or a standard one from elsewhere

Comment: Again it depends critically on your DTD (I now assume you have one). The DTD *may* define the @id attribute as of type ID in which case Vinze is correct and it is an invalid identifier.

Answer (score 0):

is there anything before the one? even if it isnt a questionmark it might be an unsupported character which is being replaced with a questionmark

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem is that `1` is not a valid identifier in XML according to NCName definition (http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xml-names-19990114/#NT-NCName).

`NCName     ::=     (Letter | '_') (NCNameChar)*`